# Dart - Polymer Custom Element not loaded

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I've been following this tutorial for Dart:

https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/

And as a quick test run I'm trying to set up a very basic thing - a page with a label and two inputs.

I'm trying to define this page as a Polymer Element and loda it, and this isn't working.  Here's the code...

index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GXMMaps</title>
    <link rel="import" href="signin.html">
    <script type="application/dart"> 
        import 'package:polymer/init.dart';
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <signin></signin>
  </body>
</html>
```

signin.html

```dart
<!-- Basic sign in form...-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <polymer-element name="signin">
 <template>
    <style>
      @host {
        :scope {
          background-color: LemonChiffon;
          text-align: center;
          display: inline-block;
          border: solid 1px;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <div>GXM Maps</div> 
    <div>
      <div>
        <input  id="username">Username</>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input  id="password">Password</>"
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script 
      type="application/dart" 
      src="signin.dart">
  </script>
 </polymer-element>
```

signin.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('signin')
class signin extends PolymerElement {
  signin.created() : super.created();
  // we'll do username and password submission here... 
}
```

If I put a header in index.html that appears just fine, and if I examine the page I can see a  element, but it's empty.

EDIT ::

I followed a comment above, and changed

```dart
<script type="application/dart"> 
    import 'package:polymer/init.dart';
```

to

```dart
<script type="application/dart"> 
    export'package:polymer/init.dart';
```

Now when I run i get the following error:

```dart
Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: Internal Dartium Exception
Stack Trace: 
#0      _Utils._register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart:461)
#1      _Utils.register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart:457)
#2      HtmlDocument.register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/build/Release/obj/global_intermediate/blink/bindings/dart/dart/html/HtmlDocument.dart:222)
#3      PolymerDeclaration.registerType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:239:22)
#4      PolymerDeclaration.register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:164:17)
#5      PolymerDeclaration._register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:114:13)
#6      PolymerDeclaration.registerWhenReady (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:109:14)
#7      _notifyType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:477:49)
#8      Polymer.register (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:62:16)
#9      _loadLibrary (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:181:25)
#10     _loadLibraries (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:89:19)
#11     _initPolymerOptimized (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:54:17)
#12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:688)
#13     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:417)
#14     _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:627)
#15     initPolymer (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:37:33)
#16     main (package:polymer/init.dart:23:22)


Exception: InvalidCharacterError: Internal Dartium Exception
  undefined (undefined:0:0)
```

Comment: There was a change a few days ago, seems like the tutorial hasn't been updated yet. Just replace your import of init.dart with an export in your html: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/VQR-VM7v-Ck

Comment: Is this the same as why the tutorial says to use query but the ide says it's depreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Should have taken a closer look at your code. The name of you element is not correct. It has to contain at least one dash. Changing it to `signin-element` will make it work.

In your `signin.html` this line:

```
<polymer-element name="signin-element">
```

in `signin.dart`:

```
@CustomTag('signin-element')
```

and finally in your `index.html`:

```
<signin-element></signin-element>
```

You should also check your html in `signin.html`. Those `</>` and `</>"` after your inputs don't belong there.

I don't know whether or not you are using the Dart Editor, but it is pretty useful and marks each of these issues with a (helpful) warning.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out yesterday actually.  That's not mentioned in the tutorial either, atleast not that I saw.